# How do Cardinalities and Generalization work in UML?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am trying to understand how Cardinalities and Relationships work with Generalization in simple UML class diagrams. I have this simple example here:

[image]

A Player owns exactly 9 Fields, but the distribution of them is irrelevant (i.e. 5 Endfields, 4 Startfields or 1 Endfield and 8 Startfields). The Field class is abstract. If i model this problem as seen above, would a Player have 9 Fields from each type? If so, how do i model this correctly?

Comment: Did you notice that the answer of bruno is flawed, as I've explained to him in a comment and in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If i model this problem as seen above, would a Player have 9 Fields from each type?

not at the same time. In your model a Player is associated to 9 Fields, knowing each Field is a *Endfield* or-exclusive a *Startfield* (supposing there are no other classes inheriting Field)

A given instance of Field cannot be both a *Endfield* and a *Startfield*, else that means Fields inherits both *Startfield* and *Endfield* (but the inheritances are in the opposite direction)

The corresponding classes in Java from your model can be :

```
abstract class Field { .... }
class Startfield extends Field { ... }
class Endfield extends Field { .. }
```

so a *Player* can be in relation with 9 *Endfields*, or-exclusive 8 *Endfields* and 1 *Startfield*, or-exclusive 7 *Endfields* and 2 *Startfield*, ..., or-exclusive 1 *Endfield* and 8 *Startfields*, or-exclusive 9 *Startfields*

If you want a Player has 9 *Startfields* and 9 *EndFields* your model can be :
[image]

---

[edit]

However if you extend your model adding an other class inheriting *Startfield* and *Endtfield* like :

[image]

in case a *Player* is associated to 9 *Bothfields* in a way it is also associated with 9 *Startfield* and 9 *Endtfield*

The multiplicity (9) of the relation concerns *Field*, for the inheriting classes that depends as you can see

Comment: I guess another way would be to make it 18 for `Field` and add a tricky OCL. Personally I prefer the above - since I would not know how to write the OCL and would anyway think it's just posing.

Comment: @bruno: Your answer is not correct, as you have confused the default meaning of a UML generalization set (see my correct answer below). Also, better drop your confusing explanation "else that means Fields inherits both Startfield and Endfield (but the inheritances are in the opposite direction)".

Comment: @GerdWagner I do not understand your remark, where do you see I speak about generalization set ? I do not

Comment: You say "each Field is a Endfield or-exclusive a Startfield" assuming that the segmentation of Field into Endfield and Startfield (called "generalization set" in UML) is disjoint (by default). But this is not the case. When such a segmentation does not have an explicit disjointness constraint in the UML Class Diagram, then its subcasses are overlapping.

Answer (score 2):

Your model does correctly express your intended meaning except that ***you need to add a disjointness constraint*** to your Endfield-Startfield segmentation (called "generalization set" in UML jargon) for making sure that a field cannot be both an end field and a start field.

As of UML 2.5, segmentations are overlapping (and incomplete) by default. See also the (always excellent) explanations on [uml-diagrams.org](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html?context=class-diagrams), which shows how to draw the disjointness constraint.